# How can I specify the window position of an external console program?

Tags: delphi, console-application

In my Win32 VCL application I am using ShellExecute to launch a number of smaller Delphi console applications. Is there a way to control the position of those console windows? I would like to launch them centered on screen.

Comment: Can you re-compile the Delphi console applications? you could get the handle of the console window via `GetConsoleWindow` and `SetWindowPos`...

Comment: @kobik I can recompile, so in all of my console apps I should use this GetConsoleWindow and SetWindowPos sequence before any code?

Comment: yes. the only defect I see is that the console window is "jumping" to it's new position.

Comment: @kobik, then you can use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) and specify its [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.

Comment: What about redirecting the console output to your own window instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have control over the console application, You could set the console window position from inside the console application itself:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Windows,
  MultiMon;

function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetConsoleWindow';

procedure SetConsoleWindowPosition;
var
  ConsoleHwnd: HWND;
  R: TRect;
begin
  ConsoleHwnd := GetConsoleWindow;
  // Center the console window
  GetWindowRect(ConsoleHwnd, R);
  SetWindowPos(ConsoleHwnd, 0,
    (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN) - (R.Right - R.Left)) div 2,
    (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN) - (R.Bottom - R.Top)) div 2,
    0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
end;

begin
  SetConsoleWindowPosition;  
  // Other code...
  Readln;
end.
```

If you can't recompile the console application, you could use `FindWindow('ConsoleWindowClass', '<path to the executable>')` to obtain the console window handle (the Title parameter could vary if it was set via `SetConsoleTitle`). 
The downside with this approach, is that the console window is seen "jumping" from it's default position to it's new position (tested with Windows XP).

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specify the window size and position in its [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure parameter. In the following example function, you can specify the size of a console window, which is then according to the specified size centered on the current desktop. The function returns process handle, if succeed, 0 otherwise:

```
function RunConsoleApplication(const ACommandLine: string; AWidth,
  AHeight: Integer): THandle;
var
  CommandLine: string;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
  FillChar(ProcessInformation, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), 0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USEPOSITION or 
    STARTF_USESIZE;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  StartupInfo.dwXSize := AWidth;
  StartupInfo.dwYSize := AHeight;
  StartupInfo.dwX := (Screen.DesktopWidth - StartupInfo.dwXSize) div 2;
  StartupInfo.dwY := (Screen.DesktopHeight - StartupInfo.dwYSize) div 2;
  CommandLine := ACommandLine;
  UniqueString(CommandLine);
  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, False,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInformation)
  then
    Result := ProcessInformation.hProcess;
end;
```